# Reading from Datatable and store in database table is taking too long?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to read Microsft Excel CSV file and save it in database. The size of file is around 500 MB. The column is more than 200 field and row is around 400000. I have read all the file in Datatable? While mapping data from Datatable to sql table it is taking very long time?Is there anyway to reduce the time?

```
public static DataTable GetRecordstoMigrate(string TableName, DataTable SourceDataRecords, List<DataMiddlewareMapping> list, string FileName)
{
        DataTable DestinationRecords = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            ExceptionLoggingInFile.SendSusssesToText("Start  Data Mapping of " + TableName);

            Console.WriteLine("Data conversion started {0}", DateTime.Now);
            list.OrderBy(o => o.Position).ToList().ForEach(c =>
            {
                DestinationRecords.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
                {
                    ColumnName = c.ColumnName,
                    DataType =
                    c.DataType == "nvarchar" ? System.Type.GetType("System.String") :
                    c.DataType == "int" ? System.Type.GetType("System.Int32") :
                    c.DataType == "bit" ? System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean") :
                    c.DataType == "decimal" ? System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal") :
                    c.DataType == "varbinary" ? System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]") :
                    c.DataType == "varchar" ? System.Type.GetType("System.String") :
                    c.DataType == "datetime" ? System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime") :
                    c.DataType == "uniqueidentifier" ? System.Type.GetType("System.Guid") :
                    c.DataType == "float" ? System.Type.GetType("System.Float") :
                    c.DataType == "date" ? System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime") :
                    c.DataType == "bigint" ? System.Type.GetType("System.Int64") :
                    System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean")
                });
            });

            foreach (DataRow SourceData in SourceDataRecords.Rows)
            {
                DataRow NewRecord = DestinationRecords.NewRow();

                switch (TableName)
                {
                    case "KYC_Individual_Details":
                        GetKYC_Individual_DetailsRecord(SourceData, list, ref NewRecord);
                        break;
                    case "KYC_Individual_Customer_Accounts":
                        GetKYC_Individual_Customer_AccountsRecord(SourceData, list, ref NewRecord);
                        break;


                }

                DestinationRecords.Rows.Add(NewRecord);
            }

            ExceptionLoggingInFile.SendSusssesToText("End  Data Mapping of " + TableName);

            ImportDataFromFile(TableName, list, DestinationRecords).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Data conversion ended {0}", DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception for Data conversion {0} {1}", DateTime.Now, ex.Message);
        }

        return DestinationRecords;
}

public static void GetKYC_Individual_DetailsRecord(DataRow SourceData, List<DataMiddlewareMapping> list, ref DataRow NewRecord)
{
        try
        {
            object _ColumnValueForCustomerType = DBNull.Value;

            var localRef = SourceData["LOCAL_REF"].ToString().Split('').ToList();
            List<string> PositionListForFamily = new List<string>();
            List<string> PositionValueListForFamily = new List<string>();

            string CustomerTypeSectorNo = SourceData["SECTOR"].ToString();

            bool resultssssss;
            int ab;
            resultssssss = int.TryParse(CustomerTypeSectorNo, out ab);
            int CustomerType = 1;

            if (resultssssss && ab >= 2002)
            {
                CustomerType = 3;
            }

            if ((localRef.Count > 36))
            {
                PositionListForFamily = localRef[37].Split('').ToList();
                PositionValueListForFamily = localRef[38].Split('').ToList();
            }

            foreach (var c in list.OrderBy(o => o.Position).ToList())

                try
                {
                    object _ColumnValue = DBNull.Value;

                    _ColumnValue = GetColumnValue(c.ColumnMapping, SourceData, c.ColumnName);

                    switch (c.ColumnName)
                    {

                        case "Id":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = Guid.NewGuid();
                            break;

                        case "CUSTOMER_NO":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "FIRST_NAME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "MIDDLE_NAME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "LAST_NAME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "FULLNAME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "COMPANY_NAME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 3 ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "REG_DATE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "DOB":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "BRANCH":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : _ColumnValue; ;
                            break;

                        case "GENDER":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 1 ? _ColumnValue.ToString() == "MALE" ? "1" : _ColumnValue.ToString() == "FEMALE" ? "2" : "0" : "0";
                            break;

                        case "MaritialStatus":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 1 ? _ColumnValue.ToString() == "SINGLE" ? "1" : _ColumnValue.ToString() == "MARRIED" ? "2" : _ColumnValue.ToString() == "DIVORCED" ? "5" : _ColumnValue.ToString() == "WIDOWED" ? "4" : "0" : "0";
                            break;

                        case "TEMPORARY_COUNTRY_CODE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "TEMPORARY_COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "PERMANENT_COUNTRY_CODE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "PERMANENT_COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "TEMPORARY_ZONE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "TEMPORARY_DISTRICT":
                            int tintDistrict = 0;

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()))
                            {
                                NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DBNull.Value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var _value = int.TryParse(_ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*"), out tintDistrict);
                                if (tintDistrict > 0)
                                    NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = Enum.Parse((typeof(District)), tintDistrict.ToString()).ToString().ToUpper();
                                else
                                    NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*");
                            }
                            break;

                        case "TEMPORARY_VDC_M":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "TEMPORARY_LOCAL":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "TEMPORARY_WARD_NO":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "PERMANENT_ZONE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "PERMANENT_DISTRICT":
                            int intDistrict = 0;

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()))
                            {
                                NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DBNull.Value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var _value = int.TryParse(_ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*"), out intDistrict);
                                if (intDistrict > 0)
                                    NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = Enum.Parse((typeof(District)), intDistrict.ToString()).ToString().ToUpper();
                                else
                                    NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*");
                            }
                            break;

                        case "PERMANENT_VDC_M":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "PERMANENT_LOCAL":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "PERMANENT_WARD_NO":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "FAXNO":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "TELNO":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "REGNO":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 2 ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "PAN_NUMBER":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 2 ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "PAN_EXP_DATE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "VATNO":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 3 ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "VAT_EXP_DATE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "MOBILE_NUMBER":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "TELEPHONE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "PASSPORT_NO":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 1 ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "PASSPORT_RELEASE_DATE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "PASSPORT_ISSUED_PLACE":
                            if (CustomerType == 1)
                            {
                                int PISSUED_PLACE_INT = 0;

                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()))
                                {
                                    NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DBNull.Value;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var _value = int.TryParse(_ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*"), out PISSUED_PLACE_INT);
                                    if (PISSUED_PLACE_INT > 0)
                                        NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = Enum.Parse((typeof(District)), PISSUED_PLACE_INT.ToString()).ToString().ToUpper();
                                    else
                                        NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DBNull.Value;
                            }
                            break;

                        case "VISA_EXPIRY_DATE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "CITIZENSHIP":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 1 ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "CITIZENSHIP_RELEASE_DATE":

                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "CITIZENSHIP_ISSUED_PLACE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "IS_MINOR":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = (CustomerType == 1 && _ColumnValue.ToString() == "1007") ? "1" : "0";
                            break;

                        case "MINOR_RELATIONSHIP":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 1 ? _ColumnValue : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "FATHERNAME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "GRANDDADNAME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "MOTHERNAME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "SPOUSE_NAME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "OCCUPATION":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "CUSTOMER_TYPE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "CUSTOMER_CATEGORY":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 1 ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "ANNUAL_INCOME":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = _ColumnValue.ToString();
                            break;

                        case "FAMILY_SIZE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 1 ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "RISK_PROFILE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CustomerType == 1 ? _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object : DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "EMAIL":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "SCORE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "PROFILE":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? "1" : _ColumnValue.ToString().ToUpper() == "HIGH" ? "3" : _ColumnValue.ToString().ToUpper() == "MEDIUM" ? "2" : _ColumnValue.ToString().ToUpper() == "LOW" ? "1" : "1";
                            break;

                        case "CRITICALITY":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "PROFILE_PIC":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "VERIFIED_BY":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : _ColumnValue.ToString().Substring(0, (_ColumnValue.ToString().Length > c.Length ? c.Length : _ColumnValue.ToString().Length)).Replace("", "*") as object;
                            break;

                        case "KYCCompletd":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ColumnValue.ToString()) ? "0" : "1";
                            break;

                        case "STAFF_CUSTOMER":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = (CustomerType == 1 && _ColumnValue.ToString() == "1002") ? "1" : "0";
                            break;

                        case "CreatedById":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CreatedById;
                            break;

                        case "ModifiedById":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CreatedById;
                            break;

                        case "AuthorisedById":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = CreatedById;
                            break;

                        case "CreatedDate":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceData[2].ToString()) ?
                                (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue :
                                DateTime.ParseExact(SourceData[2].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) as object;
                            break;

                        case "ModifiedDate":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DateTime.Now.Date;
                            break;

                        case "AuthorisedDate":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DateTime.Now.Date;
                            break;

                        case "Record_Status":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = "2";
                            break;

                        case "Deleted_Status":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = DBNull.Value;
                            break;

                        case "DataEntry":
                            NewRecord[c.Position - 1] = "2";
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionLoggingInFile.SendErrorToText(ex, "Error from GetKYC_Individual_DetailsRecord method");
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception : {0} at {1}", ex.Message, c.ColumnName);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLoggingInFile.SendErrorToText(ex, "Error from GetKYC_Individual_DetailsRecord method");
        }
}

public static async Task ImportDataFromFile(string TableName, List<DataMiddlewareMapping> list, DataTable Records)
{
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                destinationConnection.Open();

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                           new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                {

                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = string.Format("[dbo].[Temporary_{0}]", TableName);


                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 20000;
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000;

                    try
                    {
                        list.OrderBy(o => o.Position).ToList().ForEach(c =>
                        {
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping()
                            {
                                DestinationColumn = c.ColumnName,
                                SourceColumn = c.ColumnName
                            });
                        });

                        await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(Records);

                        Console.WriteLine("Total Data imported", Records.Rows.Count);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ExceptionLoggingInFile.SendErrorToText(ex, "Error from ImportDataFromFile method");
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception for Data import for sql {0} {1}", DateTime.Now, ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: What is "too long" 10 minutes? 10 hours?

Comment: more than 3 hours in my case

Comment: There are so many reasons why it could be so slow (reading the csv, computer hardware, datatypes, db connection etc). Split it all up in separate code blocks like reading csv, converting it to datatable, writing to the db etc. and optimize each one step by step.

Comment: Looking at your code, it may be due to the performance when running SqlBulkCopy. That can be optimised by altering the batch size - For a 200 field table, your current size of 20 thousand rows at a time may very well be (and probably is) too many in one go, so you might want to reduce it. Agree with VDWWD though, I would start by debugging your code and seeing exactly what is taking a long time. There are many things you can do to improve the performance of the code above

Comment: Thank you OK I will try like you say. Also,while debugging what I found is, mapping from sourceDatatable to DestinationDatatable is taking most of the time. I am confused if it is normal or taking more time since I am just using foreach loop in that function. I have four files to do on daily basis so I was in need to reduce the overall time.